# Getting an error, Port gmake not found, while trying to setup for AOSP build environment

Tags: macos, macos-sierra, macports

I'm following an instruction from https://source.android.com/setup/build/initializing to build the environment.

I'm at the section **Installing the JDK** where I have to install gmake, libsdl, git, and gnupg using MacPort.

```
POSIXLY_CORRECT=1 sudo port install gmake libsdl git gnupg
```

But I'm getting an error, `Error: Port gmake not found`.

I'm using macOS Sierra.

Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you followed the installation instructions from:

https://www.macports.org/install.php

Note that you ought to have run `sudo port -v selfupdate` to update your local copy of the port tree.

Try the `port diagnose` command to see if it detects any of the more commonly encountered problems.